# Don't build another association if one already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-forms, has-many

I have some problems getting a nested form working. In the below example I have a User that can define multiple custom labels for a post. The user should be able to enter a value for each particular label.

So one Post can have multiple labels, but should only have one value for each label! In example: Post can have a label named "Date" and also have a label named "Mood". For both labels there should be just one value.

The problem is when a User creates a Label -let say "Date"- it should only be possible to enter one value for this post for this particular label. So if a value for date is given, the form shouldn't build another field for date again. (the post already has a date)

1. User creates custom labels (this works)
2. On the edit page of the Post, User sees the labels he created in step 1 (this works)
3. User can enter a value for each of the Label (here is the problem)

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :labels
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :label_values
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :label_values, allow_destroy: true
end

class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :label_values
  belongs_to :user
end

class LabelValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :label
end
```

In my controller I have

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @labels = current_user.labels.all
    @post.label_values.build
  end

end
```

My form:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  =f.fields_for :label_values do |s|
    =s.association :label, :include_blank => false
    =s.input :value
 = f.button :submit
```

Like this, every time a User enters a value for a particular label, the next time a new label_value is build again and that is not what I want. For each label the User should be able to enter one value.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use `Label` to attach metadata to `Post` you may want to consider using a relationship somewhat like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_labels # Labels which have been used by this user.
    has_many :labels, through: :user_labels
    has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_labels
    belongs_to :user, as: :author
    has_many :labels, through: :post_labels
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_labels

    def available_labels
        Label.where.not(id: labels.pluck(:label_id))
    end
end

class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
    # @attribute name [String] The name of the label
    has_many :user_labels
    has_many :post_labels
    has_many :users, through: :user_labels
    has_many :posts, through: :post_labels
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

# Used to store label values that are attached to a post
class PostLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :label
    validates_uniqueness_of :label, scope: :post # only one label per post
    # @attribute value [String] the value of the label attached to a post
end

# Used for something like displaying the most used labels by a user  
class UserLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :label
end
```

In this setup labels act somewhat like "tags" on Stackoverflow. Each separate label is unique in the system but may be attached to many posts - by many users.

Note  the `validates_uniqueness_of :label, scope: :post` validation which ensures this.

The actuals values attached to a tag are stored on the `value` attribute of `PostLabel`. One major drawback to this approach is that you are really limited on by type of the `PostLabel` `value` column and may have to do typecasting. I really would not use it for dates as in your example as it will be difficult to do a query based on date.

```
def PostController

    def new 
        @available_labels = Label.all()
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.joins(:labels).find(params[:id])
        @available_labels = @post.available_labels
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(create_params)

        if (@post.save) 
          @post.labels.each do |l|
            @post.user.labels << l
          end
          # ...
        else
          # ...
        end
    end

    private 

    def create_params
        params.permit(:post).allow(:post_labels)
    end
end
```

## Added

This is simply some opinionated recommendations:

To add new labels to a post I would add a text input below the already assigned labels. 
I would autocomplete using `GET /labels`. and filter against the inputs already present in the form. You can allow users to create new labels on the fly by doing an ajax request to `POST /labels`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came to something. In the Post model I created:

```
def empty_labels
    Label.where.not(:id => labelValue.select(:label_id).uniq)
end

def used_simfields
    LabelValue.where(post_id: id)
end
```

Then in the view I did:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|

  -@post.used_labels.each do |used_label|
    =f.fields_for :label_values, used_label do |old_label|
      =old_label :value

  -@post.empty_labels.each do |empty_label|
    =empty_label.fields_for :label_values, @post.label_values.new do |new_label|
      =new_label.association :label
      =new_label.input :value
```

I am very sure there are nicer ways to achieve this, so new ideas are very welcome.